# Predicted probabilities with the marginaleffects package

Tags: r, marginal-effects, r-marginaleffects

I'm looking for the most user-friendly way of calculating predicted probabilities with confidence intervals from a logistic regression model using the `marginaleffects` package in R.

Let's consider a toy model:

```
mod <- glm(am ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars, family = binomial)
```

I could do

```
invlogit <- \(x) exp(x)/(1+exp(x))
hypotheses(mod, hypothesis = c("invlogit(`(Intercept)`) = 0",
                               "invlogit(`(Intercept)` + `factor(cyl)6`) = 0",
                               "invlogit(`(Intercept)` + `factor(cyl)8`) = 0"))
```

to get the predicted probabilities in the three groups given by the `cyl`-variable with corresponding confidence intervals (yeah, I know they're bad here because of the low sample, but let's forget about that).

Is there some other way of doing this where I don't have to make the `invlogit`-function and perhaps where the specification of the three groups is done a bit easier. With Stata's `margins` function you can simply write `margins cyl` or `margins var1#var2` to get the predicted probabilities for each combination of two categorical variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you just looking for `marginaleffects::marginal_means`?

```r
mod <- glm(am ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars, family = binomial)
marginaleffects::marginal_means(mod)

#> Term Value  Mean Pr(>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 %
#>  cyl     4 0.727    0.147 0.414  0.910
#>  cyl     6 0.429    0.706 0.144  0.770
#>  cyl     8 0.143    0.019 0.036  0.427
#>
#> Results averaged over levels of: cyl 
#> Columns: rowid, term, value, cyl, estimate, p.value, conf.low, conf.high, am, wts
```

Note that in any case you don't need to define `invlogit`; it does the same thing as base R's `plogis`

Comment: Yeah, either that or `predictions(mod, newdata = datagrid(cyl = c(4, 6, 8)))`. Not sure why I was overthinking this. One difference between this approach and the one in the original post is that confidence intervals here are calculated on the link scale and transformed, while the confidence intervals made by `hypotheses()` are calculated on the response scale. At least that's how it looks.

Comment: I think you're right about the order of exponentiating the confidence intervals. I think doing it this way round is the right way.